# text file turns into binary file when writing 1024 byte to it (linux)

Tags: c, linux, file, executable

I was playing with the `open` and `make` functions , so I tried to write 1024 bytes to a file
the code goes like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

main(void)
{
        int fd;
        fd = open("hellow" , O_RDWR);
        write(fd , "hello" , 1024);
}
```

when I compile this in `linux` with `gcc` it compiles fine but when I try to open `hellow` in the terminal using `less`, I get this warning :
`"hellow" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?`
when I answer yes I get the line I intended to write folowed by a full page of random symbols . So my question is , does anyone knows what causes `hellow` to be considered an a binary file and why does those random characters gets written after the intended lines.

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour. It would be entirely legit for it to wipe your home directory.

Comment: You should, right now, right away, and with greatest urgency, *stop* discarding the return value of I/O operations, and get into the habit of only ever using `write` in a loop: `for (size_t n, pos = 0; (n = write(buf + pos, 1, total_size - pos, fd)) > 0; pos += n) { }` The `write` call may write as little as one byte at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why does those random characters gets written after the intended lines?

You tell `write()` to write 1024 bytes, but you supply only 6 ("hello" plus the terminating zero), so you've (most likely) written 1018 bytes of random gibberish to your file.  Not only that, but this invokes undefined behaviour.

> what causes `hellow` to be considered an a binary file?

`less` is using a heuristic to determine whether the file is "text" or "binary"; it's looking for any characters with values outside the normal human-readable range.  You can read more about this on the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less) (see the section on character sets).

Comment: but here's the thing even when I write `write(fd , "hello" , 6)` , when I check the file I find this line `hello^@`

Comment: @FaroukJouti: You need `5`.  Or even better, just use `strlen()`.